# Where should I create a folder with my own DAGs for Airflow?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, airflow

I have to work with Airflow on Windows. I'm new to it, so I have a lot of issues.

So, I've already done all the steps from one of the tutorial using Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip
export SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes
pip install apache-airflow
```

Python version: Python2.7.15+.

I have my /home/user_name/ where I created AirflowHome folder. Then I did:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/home/user_name/AirflowHome (#wrote on the last string)
```

I ran

```
airflow initdb
```

in /home/user_name/.

Should have done this instead in /home/user_name/AirflowHome/ ?

I also ran:

```
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

It never finished (is it alright?), but it seemed to work as I was able to reach primary Airflow window.

I've already tried putting a 'dags' folder (with my own dags) to

```
/home/user_name/airflow/
/home/user_name/AirflowHome/
/home/user_name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/dag/
```

None of these showed my SampleFile.py on Airflow webserver (I checked dag_id in the file, it is alright).

Now I need to understand where I can create a 'dags' folder where I would put all of my DAGs.

I would be very grateful, if you helped me fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

In airflow.cfg I put
`dags_folder=/home/user_name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/example_dags .`

It worked.

When you need to add a file, put it in the folder and run
`airflow initdb` 
in Ubuntu. When you need to remove a file from this folder, delete the file and then sign out and sign in to Windows, then run
`airflow db init` and `airflow webserver`
in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

Correct path to your DAG folder is set in `airflow.cfg` file (it's located at `/home/user_name/AirflowHome/airflow.cfg`). Check the `dags_folder` parameter (the first one actually).

> It never finished (is it alright?)

Yes, it's ok. You can add `-D` parameter to start it in background.

BTW, as I remember, you should also run `airflow scheduler` in another terminal.

Comment: Checked airflow.cfg, doesn't solve the problem. My file still doesn't appear on webserver.
However, while running "airflow webserver" it reads DAGs from the right folder.